# Issues with reading from network stream

Tags: c#

Currently I am working on a little project which should work over the network. But I have a problem with a read method, which should read bytes from a network stream. The function reads each single bytes and when it comes to a specific byte(in my case it is ! = 33) it fires an data received event. However when the server sends several messages in a short time the read method misses some messages. Here my code:

```
public void Read()
{
    while (this.isReading == true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                continue;
            }

            List<byte> receivedBytes = new List<byte>();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

            while (this.stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                this.stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);

                // Checks if the current byte is the last byte of a protocol
                if (buffer[0] == 33)
                {
                    break;
                }

                receivedBytes.Add(buffer[0]);
            }

            this.FireOnDataReceived(receivedBytes.ToArray());
        }
        catch
        {
            this.FireOnConnectionLost();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, don't silently eat your exceptions. Get rid of your `catch` or add a real exception handler. You might be missing one.

Comment: @DavidLively Thats not the problem in my case. The read method doesn't read fast enough when the server sends several messages in a short time.

Comment: and dont poll for data available, just sit on a read

Comment: @Thomas5897 ... which is one reason to read all available data at once, then process it. Your loop approach will take many times longer to process, say, 1000 bytes than just reading it in blocks. And you can't tell that you're not getting an exception without an exception handler. Messages don't just disappear, unless the network stack runs out of buffer space, which may happen if you're processing it to slowly. Like, one byte at a time.